Find the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin x}{a+\cos x}dx$ using complex analysis
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin x}{a+\cos x}dx$$
this is from a previous test paper, and I have no idea how to do it. Mathematica gives a huge result

I wonder: is there a simple answer, and a simple method, to do the problem?

Improved : steps added, simpler hypergeometric function and asmptotics.

Aussuming $a>0$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin (x)}{a+\cos (x)}dx$$
Integrating by parts
$$\int\frac{x\sin (x)}{a+\cos (x)}dx=-x \log (a+\cos (x))+\int \log (a+\cos (x))\,dx$$
Using
$$\log (a+\cos (x))=\log(a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \,\frac {\cos^n(x)}{n\, a^n }$$
$$I=\sqrt \pi\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n^2 \, \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\,a^n}$$
Using generalized hypergeometric function
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{\pi}{2}   \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{a}\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{a^2}\right)} $$
Notice that
$$\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=\sqrt \pi\,\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2 n+1)^2 \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\,a^{2n}}$$
If $b_n$ is the summand
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{2 (n+1) (2 n+1)}{a^2 (2 n+3)^2}=\frac 1 {a^2} \Bigg(1-\frac{3}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Bigg)$$
Edit
For small values of $a$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}   \log (2 a)+\log \left(\frac{2 e}{a}\right)\,a+\frac 1 {36}\log \left(\frac{64}{e a^6}\right)\,a^3+ O(a^5)$$
For large values of $a$
$$I=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{\pi }{8 a^2}+\frac{2}{9 a^3}-\frac{3 \pi }{64 a^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^5}\right)$$


Define the function $\mathcal{I}:(-\infty,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{a\,\varphi\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}.$$
For any $a\le1$, we can rewrite the integral $\mathcal{I}$ as
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{a\,\varphi\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\varphi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{a\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{a\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{\theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{d}{d\varphi}\ln{\left(1-a\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\left[-\ln{\left(1-a\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\right].\\
\end{align}$$
Noting that $\mathcal{I}{\left(0\right)}=0$, we can express $\mathcal{I}$ through the fundamental theorem of calculus as
$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}=\mathcal{I}{\left(0\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I}{\left(x\right)}=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I}{\left(x\right)}.$$
The derivative of $\mathcal{I}$ can be evaluated using the Leibniz integral rule for differentiation under the integral sign:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I}{\left(x\right)}
&=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\left[-\ln{\left(1-x\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[-\ln{\left(1-x\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}{1-x\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}{1-x\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\theta=2\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)-x\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\left(1-t^{2}\right)}{\left[\left(1-x\right)+\left(1+x\right)t^{2}\right]\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)+\left(1+x\right)t^{2}}-\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\right]\\
&=-\frac{2}{x}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)+\left(1+x\right)t^{2}}\right]\\
&=-\frac{2}{x}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)t^{2}}\right]\\
&=-\frac{2}{x}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{1+u^{2}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\,t=u\right]}\\
&=-\frac{2}{x}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right].\\
\end{align}$$
Then, for $a\in[-1,1]$ we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{I}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x}\left[-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x}\left[-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi-2\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\int_{1}^{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{(-2)}{1-y^{2}}\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi-2\arctan{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}}{\left(\frac{2}{1+y}\right)\sqrt{y}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\left[-\frac{\pi}{1-y^{2}}+\frac{\pi-2\arctan{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}}{\left(1-y\right)\sqrt{y}}\right]\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[-\frac{2\pi\,t}{1-t^{4}}+\frac{2\pi-4\arctan{\left(t\right)}}{1-t^{2}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{y}=t\right]}\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[-\frac{2\pi\,t}{1-t^{4}}+\frac{\pi+4\arctan{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1-t^{2}}\right]\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{\pi}{1-t^{2}}-\frac{2\pi\,t}{1-t^{4}}+\frac{4\arctan{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1-t^{2}}\right]\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{\pi\,(1-t)}{\left(1+t\right)\left(1+t^{2}\right)}+\frac{4\arctan{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1-t^{2}}\right]\\
&=\pi\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1-t}{\left(1+t\right)\left(1+t^{2}\right)}+\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{4\arctan{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}}{1-t^{2}}\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u}{1+u^{2}}+2\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\arctan{\left(u\right)}}{u};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-t}{1+t}=u\land z:=\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(1+z^{2}\right)}+2\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(z\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\right)}+2\operatorname{Ti}_{2}{\left(\frac{a}{1+\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$
where $\operatorname{Ti}_{2}$ is the so-called inverse tangent integral function.


Assuming $a>0$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin x}{a+\cos x} dx\overset{ibp}=\frac\pi2\ln a+ I(a)
$$
where
$I(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(a+\cos x) dx$, which has two distinctive cases
\begin{align}
I’(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac1{a+\cos x} dx=
\begin{cases}
\frac2{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}, &a<1\\
\frac2{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}, &a>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, respectively
\begin{align}
I(a<1)=& \ I(0)+\int_0^a I’(t)dt\\
=& \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x) dx+\int_0^a 
 \frac{2 \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\\
=&-\frac\pi2\ln2-2\int_0^{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}}\frac{\ln s}{1+s^2}ds\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\bigg( \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}=\frac{1-s}{1+s}\bigg)\\
\overset{ibp}=&-\frac\pi2\ln2-2\ln b\tan^{-1}b + 2\Im\text{Li}_2(i b), \>\>\>\>\> b =\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}a\\
\\
 I(a>1)=& \ I(1)+\int_1^a I’(t)dt\\
=& \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(1+\cos x) dx+\int_1^a 
 \frac{2 \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{t-1}{t+1}}}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt\\
=&\ 2G-\frac\pi2\ln2+2\int^1_{a-\sqrt{a^2-1}}\frac{\frac\pi4-\tan^{-1} s}{s}ds\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\bigg( \sqrt{\frac{t-1}{t+1}}=\frac{1-s}{1+s}\bigg)\\
=&\ \frac\pi2\ln\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}{2}+ 2\Im\text{Li}_2(i a-i\sqrt{a^2-1})
\end{align}
